# Directshow Wpf program shows black screen but graphstudio works well

Tags: wpf, video, directshow

Like the title,Directshow Wpf program shows black screen but graphstudio works well.I am sure the filter in the graphstudio is the same as I use in the program.And mediaplayer works well too.What's the matter?

Comment: To help you we need more info's. What format and codecs are the video file, how do you play the file with directshow in wpf  (evr presenter or media element), and a screenshot of the filtergraph.

Comment: Also, please provide us with a [mcve] (including the **relevant** code). Generally I would suggest you to read the [ask] topics too. Currently, your question lacks a lot of information and can be considered as too broad (so it might be closed soon).